# SCSS styles not applying after refactor to scss module

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I am refactoring an app, so that component styles will be isolated from global styles to css modules. However, I have encountered an issue, where the styles are not applying.

Original code:

```
<div className={`explainer-callout-wrapper position-${callOutPosition}`}>
```

Code for the styling in question:

```
.explainerCalloutWrapper {
  position: relative;

  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
    right: 0;
  }

  &.position1 {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
      top: 4rem;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
      top: 6rem;
    }
  }

  &.position2 {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
      top: 7rem;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
      top: 11rem;
    }
  }

  &.position3 {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
      top: 11.5rem;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
      top: 18rem;
    }
  }

  &.position4 {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
      top: 16rem;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
      top: 25.5rem;
    }
  }

  &.position5 {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
      top: 20.5rem;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
      top: 31.5rem;
    }
  }
}
```

${callOutPosition} comes in via props, to determine the position of the element and applies relevant styles from the SCSS module.

In the original code, when in normal desktop view, the styling applies classes from &.position1 and applied the `top: 4rem;` styling.

However in the refactored code, which makes use of the clsx library and css module, the latter class of `position${callOutPosition}` is not applying the mentioned styling.

Here is the refactored code:

```
<div className={clsx(styles.explainerCalloutWrapper, `position-${callOutPosition}`)}>
```

What I am missing or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: What are the values for `md` and `lg`? If they are variables you must use `$md` to tell the compiler that

Comment: The values come in from bootstrap global styles, which are imported at the beginning of the scss file

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
<div className={clsx(styles.explainerCalloutWrapper, styles[`position${callOutPosition}`])}>
```